# Accessing nodes for a newly injected FXML file in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxmlloader

I have an FXML file whose controller is set through:

```
fxmlloader.load(url);
fxmlloader.setController(<homeControllerObject>)
```

Now after a button click i load another fxml inside the current fxml with:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(HomeController.class
              .getResourceAsStream("sample.fxml"));
pane1.getChildren().add(root);
```

How can i access a label defined inside 'sample.fxml' in HomeController. I tried using

```
@FXML
private Label label;
```

at the top in HomeController but since the injection happens later on, value of label is always null.
Any ideas about how can i access those new nodes?

Comment: The structure of the root node would have to be known to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: After loading `sample.fxml` do `fxmlLoader.getController().getLabel()` or something like this. However IMHO it's bad design to allow direct access to the `Node`s of the subcontroller...

Comment: Cant i somehow set the controller of the sample.fxml to the current class i.e.,HomeController? I would prefer not to user separate controlleres for the injected FXML

Answer (score 0):

You should define an fx:id for your label and use this id as a field name. For example, if fx:id is myLabel then you can use it in your controller like this:
@FXML
Label myLabel;